# Take every odd row of from column A and add 20 to the element in the second column

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following matrix, which can be defined as `np.array` instead, too:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.matrix([[2, 2], [4, 4], [1, 6], [6, 8],[7,9],[8,10],[10,12]])

matrix([[ 2,  2],
        [ 4,  4],
        [ 1,  6],
        [ 6,  8],
        [ 7,  9],
        [ 8, 10],
        [10, 12]])
```

I want to take every odd row from column A and add 20 to the element in the second column. Following is what I am trying to achieve for an example (where we start modifying from the second odd row index to one row index left to the last), I have used for loop but without success. Is there a efficient way of doing this ?

```
matrix([[ 2,  2],
        [ 4,  4],
        [ 1,  26],
        [ 6,  8],
        [ 7,  29],
        [ 8, 10],
        [10, 12]])
```

Comment: Why is only the second column of rows 3 and 5 added 20?

Comment: The end result that you wish to achieve is inconsistent with what you have as question. Please state what is the correct end result

Comment: That's what i am trying to get. if the first column is odd then add 20 to the 2nd column of the matrix.

Comment: `np.matrix` is deprecated, use `np.array` instead

Comment: Numpy officially does not recommend the use of `np.matrix`, consider using `np.array` instead: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
# use where to find the rows where the first column values are odd
# and add 20 to the corresponding second column values
array[np.where(array[:,0]%2==1)[0], [1]] += 20
array
#matrix([[ 2,  2],
#        [ 4,  4],
#        [ 1, 26],
#        [ 6,  8],
#        [ 7, 29],
#        [ 8, 10],
#        [10, 12]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Coding approach:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    if (array[i,0]%2) == 1:
        array[i,1] = array[i,1]+20
        
array
```

Output:

```
matrix([[ 2,  2],
        [ 4,  4],
        [ 1, 26],
        [ 6,  8],
        [ 7, 29],
        [ 8, 10],
        [10, 12]])
```

Comment: As [it is mentioned by Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277360/loop-through-every-odd-rows-of-from-the-matrix-and-add-number-in-the-second-colu/72278053#comment127695992_72278053) in the comments, too, I suggest to solve such problem using my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing:

```
# if all the odd row indices on the second column is the aim:
array[::2, 1] += 20

# [[ 2 22]
#  [ 4  4]
#  [ 1 26]
#  [ 6  8]
#  [ 7 29]
#  [ 8 10]
#  [10 32]]

# if all the odd row indices (start from the second odd row index to one row index before the end) on the second column is the aim:
array[2:-1:2, 1] += 20

# [[ 2  2]
#  [ 4  4]
#  [ 1 26]
#  [ 6  8]
#  [ 7 29]
#  [ 8 10]
#  [10 12]]
```

small explanation: it will works on column with index `1` and on rows every other one (`::2`); it will starts from the row with index `2` (`2::`) and continue until the row index `-1` (`:-1:`). So if we have, e.g.,:

```
array[1:-2:3, 1] += 20

# [[ 2  2]
#  [ 4 24]
#  [ 1  6]
#  [ 6  8]
#  [ 7 29]
#  [ 8 10]
#  [10 12]]
```